# List names alphabetically with count in desc order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I need a solution with a mysql query, it's basically depends on the two order by fields, here is the scenario,

I have a table, say `abc` with the fields like,

```
auto_id  name  count_values

1        html      10  
2        css       29  
3        js        65  
4        jquery     3  
5        html5      9  
6        asp       58  
7        php       34  
8        xcode      6  
....
```

so on (more than 100 records)

So I need the result, which basically list all the name with count_values, based on the
`name > alphabetically` + `count_values > maximum`

I have tried with

```
Select 
  distinct name,
  count_values 
from 
  abc 
where 
  count_values > 0 
group by 
  name 
order by 
  name asc, count_values desc 
limit 0, 10;
```

But the result is showing the names in alphabetical order where as I have some big count on xcode data row which is not in the list.

Comment: Do you need to sum those count_values too when you group? Or just need any 1 record for any 1 name

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ, no its not the sum, just I need the list of rows which includes the name alphabetical order with those which have max count_value. event if I have limit it 5 or 50

Comment: because, it might possible we have duplicate entry from user end

Comment: also I have tried with SUM, but result is not as expected, its only shows the alphabetical order, and I missed the xcode row

Comment: There's no need to repeat information in the title of your question that you can indicate with tags. The tag system works very well here; please don't try and help it. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will output the 10 rows with the highest `count_values`, in order by `name`.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT name, MAX(count_values) count_values
      FROM abc
      WHERE count_values > 0
      GROUP BY name
      ORDER BY count_values DESC
      LIMIT 10) x
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: But this can show duplicate names if they fill the criteria, isn't it?

Comment: I have added GROUP BY, duplicate records are omitted. I think it'll help me. Let me verify once more time.

Comment: I didn't realize there could be duplicates (I don't think your example has any). I changed the query to use `MAX(count_values)`.